# Joomla 3.5 com_ajax not found

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.5

I have update my Joomla from V3.4 to V3.5 and below error is showing.

> "NetworkError: 404 Component not found. -
>   http://example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_ajax&group=system&plugin=sendStats&format=raw"

I tried to place `die('here');` in `administrator/components/com_ajax/ajax.php` and there is no output.

Comment: In the Joomla backend, go to `Extensions >> Manage >> Manage`, then see if `Ajax Interface` is in the list of installed extensions

Comment: only `plg_ajax_zentools2 ` found.

Comment: I just check in default joomla 3.5 there is no `ajax` in `Extensions >> Manage >> Manage`

Comment: Ok now try going to `Extensions >> Manage >> Discover`. If you see it there, install it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the Ajax Interface has somehow been lost in the Joomla update, however the files are still there.

I've heard of this happening before and believe it's a Joomla bug.

Seeing as the files **are** still there, go to your Joomla back-end, then go to:

> Extensions >> Manage >> Discover

You should see the **Ajax Interface** component appear, which you can then install.